# How to use patchValue with FormArray in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a FormGroup that has an element like this.

```
books: this.fb.array([this.buildBookFormGroup()])
```

fb is the FormBuilder. The buildBookFormGroup() function returns a FromGroup so that I can add/remove multiple books from the same form.

```
buildBookFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this.fb.group({
      author: new FormControl(''),
      price: new FormControl(0),
    });
  }
```

I have functions for getting the form controls, for adding and for removing formgroups from the 'books' control.

Now, I have added multiple books using this form and persisted them. I want to make an edit page where I want to fetch the existing data and populate the form. For that, I am using 'patchValue'. However, patchValue is not working for FormArray. Looked into multiple questions and answers, and I'm further confused. Here is how I was patching.

```
if (this.bookshop.books.length > 0) {
      let booksFormGroupArray: FormGroup[] = [];
      this.bookshop.books.forEach((book, index) => {
        booksFormGroupArray.push(this.buildBookFormGroup());
        Object.keys(booksFormGroupArray[index].controls).forEach(key => {
          booksFormGroupArray[index].patchValue({
            [key]: book[key]
          })
        })
      });
      this.bookForm.patchValue({
        books: this.fb.array(booksFormGroupArray)
      });
    }
```

Only the first book object is getting inserted into the 'books' of the form. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `patchValue` you have to provide value not an array of FormGroups.

So, you patch value directly to dynamically created `FormGroup`s and push the group into the `controls` of your `array`, it will work.

So, new patching method will be:

```
if (this.bookshop.books.length > 0) {
      const bookArray = this.bookForm.get("books") as FormArray;
      bookArray.clear();

      this.bookshop.books.forEach(book => {
        const group = this.buildBookbookFormGroup();
        Object.keys(group.controls).forEach(key => {
          group.patchValue({
            [key]: book[key]
          });
        });
        bookArray.controls.push(group);
      });
    }
```

And if you want to iterate over `FormArray` values, then:

```
get books() {
    return (this.bookForm.get("books") as FormArray).controls.map(m => m.value);
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let book of books">
    <p>Author: {{book.author}}, &emsp; Price: {{book.price}}</p>
</div>
```

**Working demo** at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dncasn?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

**Result:**

[image]